# cx_Freeze error: no commands supplied

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm trying to create a executable from my .py file.

I did this:

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("Cobra.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(name="Snake Python", options={"build_exe":{"packages":["pygame","time","sys","os","random"]}}, executables = executables)
```

And run from Python GUI. It returns the follow erros:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/victor/Desktop/tcc/Jogo_Cobra/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    cx_Freeze.setup(name="Snake Python", options={"build_exe":{"packages":["pygame","time","sys","os","random"]}}, executables = executables)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 365, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
    raise SystemExit(gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg)
SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help
error: no commands supplies
```

I using Python 3.2 on windows 8.1 and cx_Freeze-4.3.2.win32-py3.2

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to supply a command via command line, you can have your script do it for you.

Place this in your code before `cx_Freeze.setup`, and you can run it without adding parameters yourself:

```
import sys
sys.argv.append("build")
```

This would be the same as running your file like this:

```
python setup.py build
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually pass a command to `setup.py` to tell it to build the executable

```
python setup.py build
```

> This command will create a subdirectory called `build` with a further subdirectory starting with the letters `exe.` and ending with the typical identifier for the platform that distutils uses

Alternately you can have it build the executable and wrap it in an installer for easy distribution

```
python setup.py bdist_msi
```